# How to Detect Key in Flutter for iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, keyboard-events

I am trying to detect when a user presses the backspace key. I have a TextField wrapped in a RawKeyboardListener which works as expected for Android, but does not seem to work for iOS. What am I missing?

In my code i attempted to check if the detected pressed key equals the logicalkeyboard.backspace or the physicalkeyboard.backspace. I'm noticing on iOS that a key is not being detected so it would seem as if the issue is the RawKeyboardListener not able to detect a pressed key?

```
RawKeyboardListener(
                          focusNode: FocusNode(),
                          onKey: (key) {
                            setState(() {
                              print('stuff');
                              //LogicalKeyboardKey.backspace
                              if (Platform.isIOS) {
                                if (key.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.backspace) {
                                  print('this is working');
                                }
                              }
                              if (key.logicalKey == PhysicalKeyboardKey.backspace) {
                                detectDeleteKey = true;
                                // birthDateController.text.replaceRange(
                                //     birthDateController.text.length - 1, null, '');
                              }
                              else {
                                detectDeleteKey = false;
                              }
                            });
                        },
                          child: RegistrationFieldRow(
                            leftTextCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none,
                            leftTextInputType: TextInputType.number,
                            leftController: birthDateController,
                            leftOnChanged: (String value) {
                              setState(() {
                                birthDateResult = birthDateRuleValidation(
                                  birthDateController,
                                  10,
                                  value,
                                  {
                                    'numbersOnly': 'birthDateNumbersOnlyChar',
                                    'charValidationList': 'birthDateChars',
                                    'maxCharCount': 'birthDateMaxCharCount',
                                    'charCount': 'birthDateCharCount',
                                    'ageCheck': 'birthDateAgeVerification'
                                  },
                                  detectDeleteKey)!;

                                if (birthDateResult != '') {
                                  birthDateRuleCheck = true;
                                }
                                else {
                                  birthDateRuleCheck = false;
                                }
                              });
                            },
                            leftFieldPrefixIcon: const Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.calendarDay,
                            size: 15.0,
                            color: ePrimaryAccentColor,),
                            leftFieldHintText: 'Birth Date',
                            rightController: zipCodeController,
                            rightTextCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none,
                            rightTextInputType: TextInputType.number,
                            rightOnChanged: (String value) async {
                              locationDataAutoFill();
                            },
                            rightFieldPrefixIcon: const Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.globe,
                            size: 15.0,
                            color: ePrimaryAccentColor,),
                            rightFieldHintText: 'Zip Code',
                          ),
                        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Android:

```
event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.backspace
```

iOS, Android:

```
event.physicalKey == PhysicalKeyboardKey.backspace
```

Comment: this won't work on iOS soft keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't, check this [known Flutter issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14809) and [this article](https://medium.com/super-declarative/why-you-cant-detect-a-delete-action-in-an-empty-flutter-text-field-3cf53e47b631) for explanation.

In [this SOF answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77208772/5502121) I suggested a workaround, which is more like a dirty hack if you need to track the "Backspace" keys to change the focus.